# Why cookie is null?

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

I make an webserver with lamp(linux+apache+mysql+php).I want to set cookie to hold user information such as userid,username.So the load.php is like this:

```
....
///login successful
session_start(); 
$_COOKIE["userid"]=$userid;

$response["success"]=1;
$response["message"]="load successful";
echo json_encode($response); 
...
```

In Android LoadActivity I create a class WebLoader extends AsyncTask,and I override the function `String doInBackground(String... params)` like this:

```
client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url_up);
...
HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);                 
HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
CookieStore mCookieStore = client.getCookieStore();
List<Cookie> cookies = mCookieStore.getCookies();
if(cookies.isEmpty())
   Log.d("cookie","cookie is none");
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
 if("userid".equals(cookies.get(i).getName()))
 {
        userid=Integer.parseInt(cookies.get(i).getValue());                 
  }
}
```

When I run the app, logcat says:cookie is none.
Why Cookie is none? I have already set it at load.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set cookies with [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). For your example:

```
setcookie("userid", $userid, time() + 60*60*24, "/");
```

This will set a cookie named `userid` with the value `$userid` and will expire 31 days from when it is set.

Comment: Sorry,but cookie is none too.

Comment: Did you try with HttpGet instead of HttpPost? And are you sure the `url_up` is valid? I've also added the path parameter. Can you try that as well?

Comment: Thank you, I finally find that it is wrong with php script, I didn't change it privilege correctly. When I change it with:sudo chmod 777 xxx.php , and all works well!